# Toast showing for less than a second in Android API 28

Tags: android, android-emulator, toast

I'm emulating my app in Android Studio emulator with API 28 and in it a Toast defined with the LENGTH_LONG parameter is displaying for less than a second, so it's basically impossible to read it on time.

It has successfully displayed the time it should in APIs 18 to 27 so this looks more of an emulator error than a real issue but I'd like to confirm and now if there's something to do in case this would be real behavior in Android API 28 physical device.

Is this a bug? If not, how to solve it?

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @TheWanderer, are you using emulator or real device? If it's real device it's clearly an emulator bug.

Comment: On an emulator.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help, anyway it's to guess that it must be problem from my computer, so I guess I'll ignore it.